# Graph depth first search sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

So I wrote a Graph class and I can't seem to do a depth first search on it properly depending on the sequencing of nodes. Here's what I mean:

If my graph looks like this:

```
A-B-D
|/
C
```

The DFS returns: "ABC"

But when it looks like this:

```
A-B
| |
D C
|
E
```

It will print ABCDE correctly.

The problem I've found lies in my getUnvisitedAdjacentNode() function. Here is the function:

```
    public int getUnvisitedAdjacentNode(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.nodeList.size(); i++) {
        if (this.edges[n][i] == 1 && this.nodeList.get(i).wasVisited == false) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The problem, I've found is because it goes in "order" (just a for loop) , it will never get traverse D in the first situation because B gets visited and after C gets visited, B simply get's popped off of the stack. Maybe this isn't the problem.

Here's the code for my actual DFS traversal.

```
   public void depthFirstTraverse() {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

    nodeList.get(0).wasVisited = true;
    System.out.println(nodeList.get(0).item);
    stack.push(nodeList.get(0));

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        int nextNode = this.getUnvisitedAdjacentNode(stack.peek().index);

        if (nextNode == -1) {
            stack.pop();
        } else {
            nodeList.get(nextNode).wasVisited = true;
            System.out.println(nodeList.get(nextNode).item);
            stack.push(nodeList.get(nextNode));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
        nodeList.get(i).wasVisited = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately I found my own mistake, the code above is all correct, except it was in the code that I hadn't pasted.

In case anybody cares, the problem lied in the fact that I completely disregarded the fact that ArrayLists have an "IndexOf()" method (stupid, I know) and decided to hack my own "index" field into my Node class. When dealing with my own indices, I had a minor bug which screwed up the traversal.

So the old line in my DFS algorithm looks like this:

```
int nextNode = this.getUnvisitedAdjacentNode(stack.peek().index);
```

But it should be:

```
int nextNode = this.getUnvisitedAdjacentNode(this.nodeList.indexOf(stack.peek()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it.  If you pop a node off of the stack, you need to make sure that  **all**  of its unvisited neighbors are on the stack first.  Otherwise, there's no guarantee that everyone will be visited.

For example, in the first diagram you gave, if node A is visited first, and then node B, either node C or D will be visited next.  However, if you only push one of them onto the stack, and then remove B, there will be no way of reaching the last one.

So what you may want to do it write a function getAllUnvisitedAdjacentNodes and push **all** of them onto the stack before you pop.

Comment: @veer.  Not sure what you mean.  He doesn't push any neighbors that have been visited, but he pops nodes off before each of their neighbors are pushed.  Hence the situation above

Comment: Yeah, Brian, I check all of my neighbors. Look carefully. The code works now. Check my updated solution that I posted. Sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: i mark a node as visited, then i push it. i then proceed to go forward , and visit an adjacent node, mark as visited and push it. if i get to a leaf node that doesn't have any adjacent ones, i go backwards on the stack popping off visited ones and proceeding to adjacent ones and so on.

Comment: Sorry @BrianKocoloski :-p he only pops when there are no more neighbors to visit.

Comment: Ahhh, apologies.  I didn't notice that.  Glad you figured it out